# couchdb 1.5.1 on ubuntu server 14.04 64bit OS Process Error

Tags: couchdb, ubuntu-14.04

after installing couchdb 1.5.1 on a brand new ubuntu 14.04 64 bit server installation I had some trouble with Spidermonkey (mozjs24).

after puting 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse' in my trusty /etc/apt/sources.list it looked like that everything was fine, but:

Now I'm getting an 'OS Process Error {os_process_error,{exit_status,127}}' and the wiki http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Error_messages only tells me that there is an issue with spidermonkey and I have to look here: 'http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_SpiderMonkey'

The tipps on this page didn't work for me so that I hat to install the raring sources??

any Ideas how to proceed ??

Thanks
Pitt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SpiderMonkey version above 1.8.5 (24 is above) is not supported and wouldn't work with CouchDB. You have to downgrade it to 1.8.5. If you have installed CouchDB from some deb package, feel free to fill bug report about wrong dependency!

Comment: Ok, I downgraded to spidermonkey 1.8.5 AND couchdb to 1.5.0 from source .... Seems to work now...

Comment: @pdewaard I wouldn't recommend you to use 1.5.0 due to active [CVE-2014-2668](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/cve/2014-2668.html#cve-2014-2668) issue which was fixed in 1.5.1 (or unless if you know how to workaround it).